# How can I get a child component's watcher's updated value from parent component in Vue 2?

Tags: vue.js

I have two components that are in a parent-child relationship. In the child select component I've defined a *watcher* for the currently selected value and I want the parent to get the updated value whenever it changes. I tried to use events but the parent can only listen to its own vm.

In the child component

```
watch: {
  selected (value) {
    this.$emit('selectedYearChange', value)
  }
}
```

In the parent

```
mounted () {
  this.$on('selectedYearChange', function (value) {
    this.selectedYear = value
  })
}
```

This obviously doesn't work because of the reason I mentioned above.
I wasn't able to find relevant examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup an event listener on the child component element itself where its used in the parent and pass it a method to be executed

```
//parent component
<div id="app>
    <child-comp @selected-year-change='changeYear'></child-comp>
</div>
```

In your parent component use the method `changeYear` to change the value of `selectedYear'

```
methods:{
    //you get the event as the parameter
    changeYear(value){
        this.selectedYear = value
    }
}
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/39jaefy5/)

And avoid using camelCase for event names use kebab-case instead as HTML attributes are case-insensitive and may cause problems

Comment: This worked and for anyone wondering [here's](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case) the documentation for what Vamsi said about kebab-case usage.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<Parent>
  <Child @selected-year-change=HandleChange(data)></Child>
</Parent>
```

Javascript/Child Component:

```
watch: {
  selected (value) {
    this.$emit('selectedYearChange', value)
  }
}
```

Javascript/Parent Component:

```
   HandleChange: function(data){}
```

good luck. maybe work!

Comment: Event listener should be on the childComponent not the parent and do not use fat arrow functions with methods